# Using EL expression inside ID field (Spring WebFlow)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have a constant class

```
@Component
public class NameConstants implements Serializable{
    public final static String NAME = "randomName";
    public static String getNAME() {
        return NAME;
    }   
}
```

And the following webflow doesn't seems to work for me:

```
<subflow-state id="#{NameConstants.NAME }" subflow="someflow">
```

Is it possible to use EL expression inside the ID field?
I keep getting the error:

```
'#{NameConstants.NAME }'is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why will you use a constant as id for an subflow state? I guess it makes no sense to use an external object to set an id to an id field of a flow state.

You can try this

```
<subflow-state id="#{T(com.foo.NameConstants).NAME}" subflow="someflow">
<!-- NameConstants#getNAME should be called -->
```

I haven't test this solution.

Why is `NameConstants` a with `@Component` annotated? I think it should also work with a simple Pojo or an Enum. I never tried to use EL in id field of a flow state.

We use EL expressions like this:

```
<subflow-state id="choose-address-subflow" subflow="address">
    <input name="addressTypeId" value="T(org.our.company.domain.Address$Type).DELIVERY.getId()" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    ...
</subflow-state>
```

Where `org.shop.domain.Address$Type` is a nested enum in domain model `org.shop.domain.Address` which can be seen on `$` between `Address` and `Type`.

Another examble is storing a value in flow scope and access it in an decision state

```
<view-state id="summary" view="some-view">
    <on-entry>
       <!-- value can also be defined in some external objects like Address$Type-->
       <set name="flowScope.nextState" value="'is-submitted'" type="java.lang.String"/> 
    </on-entry>
    ...
</view-state>
```

in decision state

```
<decision-state id="is-check-successful">
    <if test="action.isCheckSuccessful(flowRequestContext)"
        <!-- if check returns true, next state is is-submitted -->
        then="#{flowScope.nextState}" 
        else="first-state"/>
</decision-state>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can by doing it like this

```
#{T(com.foo.NameConstants).NAME}
```

Comment: What is the T for? Casting?

Comment: T is for generic type T, if you need more information about this, please check the Spring Expression Language reference on types 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types

Comment: Make sure that you are putting the entire package name of your class

Comment: There is another solution, but it is clean as this one, you can put your static value in any of the variable scopes that the webflow has access to; conversionScope, flowScope, ... etc. check more here if needed http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/el.html